# Have Some problems with my footer

Tags: html, css

I am working on a simple html webpage that contained a footer But the footer does not work correctly !

I want the footer be at the bottom of the page but ... !

and this is the problem :

[image]

here is a demo of my webpage ( sorry for the language ;) ) :http://gooloop.ir/dl/site/temp.html

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your question. The link might die.

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow:hidden` to `.content`.

The content was collapsing upon itself as it didn't have any defined dimensions, and thus the footer was placed over it.

```css
.content {
  width: 962px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It will work. Tested in the dev tool.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that!